# Excavation Study

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*Layer by layer, we continue our journey to the center.*

## Excavation area (in order)

[image: excavation_study_grids]

## Excavation plans

Expect plenty of overlap!

[image: excavation_study_plans]

---

Answer is a **thematic word phrase.**

---

Text transcription of the excavation area:

```
F   S   P   Z   Z   K   H   D   H   K   H   V   R   M   J
S   K   G   P   U   O   W   S   Q   O   D   I   E   B   T
M   A   D   H   K   H   V   R   M   J   J   O   O   R   A
M   T   S   E   X   D   M   T   B   T   E   U   M   E   A
J   A   E   R   I   J   K   Y   R   A   T   E   R   R   U
L   J   L   I   T   H   O   S   P   H   E   R   E   E   V
J   B   C   Y   E   R   X   U   A   U   M   Z   K   H   H
C   Q   X   P   Y   G   K   B   Y   V   B   U   X   T   H
T   F   N   U   M   V   R   O   Q   H   W   A   A   H   Z
H   G   O   W   B   V   J   G   S   P   D   P   H   J   E
P   W   Q   D   U   L   O   X   S   Z   G   E   N   N   Z
M   V   C   D   H   C   U   F   W   K   H   I   O   X   G
B   V   T   G   E   P   N   J   B   Z   M   E   A   J   Z
U   L   C   O   D   I   K   C   K   A   Y   N   R   N   J
H   C   U   F   W   K   M   I   O   L   M   A   F   E   G

U   Z   G   B   P   W   J   V   B   R   O   S   K   K   G
Q   E   S   Y   K   D   K   J   T   V   I   Y   O   I   F
V   L   C   J   X   T   A   F   E   X   B   Y   N   F   M
P   V   Y   R   M   A   N   N   J   L   L   G   J   Q   T
C   B   F   T   E   Q   T   V   W   X   I   C   W   Y   B
E   L   V   V   H   F   N   U   V   E   O   M   P   B   N
Z   A   J   B   H   E   O   W   N   L   S   R   U   F   I
P   O   O   U   P   W   N   D   X   E   M   P   G   O   C
O   O   F   U   H   H   C   O   C   H   S   R   Z   G   Z
G   H   F   S   H   G   T   J   P   J   U   V   J   C   Y
Q   T   Y   J   A   W   C   I   C   P   V   Q   D   N   E
K   S   M   S   L   G   O   V   U   B   O   G   E   R   R
R   Z   L   A   L   U   L   Z   Q   Y   R   S   I   F   M
U   M   F   P   W   R   Q   J   T   V   R   W   I   U   H
N   Y   W   N   V   F   J   Z   A   W   J   T   U   N   D

E   E   C   D   A   F   V   B   O   A   S   C   L   J   A
D   U   V   O   F   H   M   D   O   U   Z   Z   I   N   R
O   Y   V   B   L   T   H   C   W   F   W   G   W   O   S
H   Q   B   F   P   P   M   E   A   H   R   I   P   F   V
Z   B   O   S   O   A   B   S   Q   W   G   Z   Y   J   P
M   N   H   L   S   I   L   P   D   S   P   L   U   I   A
Q   K   Y   U   O   J   C   O   P   C   D   G   S   Q   Q
O   O   R   W   S   V   X   I   K   X   D   S   E   Z   K
J   A   M   B   P   W   G   D   J   Z   Y   Z   F   S   J
B   J   G   D   H   R   T   Y   T   T   Z   E   N   C   M
Q   Z   R   C   E   B   A   R   A   Z   V   X   E   W   S
C   G   M   Q   R   Z   E   L   J   G   R   I   D   Q   U
G   D   F   L   F   Q   H   U   G   U   H   J   O   Q   H
W   H   I   A   H   E   S   W   S   A   S   T   S   I   B
J   B   A   Z   V   L   Y   R   P   D   R   K   F   A   I

H   M   V   Z   Z   F   Z   C   W   N   G   L   S   B   R
O   D   G   J   G   H   B   S   W   C   W   W   D   T   K
W   P   H   H   C   T   K   E   F   O   K   C   V   N   M
J   Q   S   E   D   D   M   P   E   E   Z   Q   D   O   K
N   V   A   J   U   H   Q   T   H   Q   C   I   V   L   V
H   H   O   L   J   Q   J   Q   A   C   S   V   U   I   Q
H   S   A   M   P   G   O   F   R   P   Z   J   K   Q   C
Y   H   A   C   C   I   C   C   W   G   P   L   U   G   G
B   T   O   Y   X   F   O   M   K   Z   D   P   J   H   D
J   E   T   S   T   G   N   M   C   K   H   Z   F   W   A
N   E   A   C   O   H   I   J   F   N   J   Y   F   Q   G
U   V   A   E   Y   R   F   K   L   N   P   I   B   K   A
L   Y   P   F   M   N   A   N   J   V   I   V   O   E   F
P   H   L   D   V   T   Z   I   T   L   S   D   O   O   H
I   B   E   I   M   W   L   Y   W   O   E   B   O   M   P

E   H   G   J   D   M   Q   T   M   C   T   I   J   O   S
O   O   J   Q   C   K   W   F   B   B   D   K   Z   R   P
G   G   B   I   M   C   G   U   A   F   O   Y   I   R   B
V   A   E   S   B   F   I   F   I   Q   K   V   F   H   Z
G   E   Q   Y   K   K   T   P   C   L   P   I   T   G   L
W   L   W   J   A   C   T   I   P   J   E   F   U   W   W
R   L   C   F   Y   Z   N   H   Z   M   B   A   R   G   F
K   Q   D   H   U   Q   I   E   C   E   X   O   J   J   C
D   W   D   Y   L   P   Y   R   L   M   C   Y   I   G   K
Q   O   P   F   T   J   K   V   D   R   M   L   V   V   F
F   O   V   N   S   Z   Z   O   E   Y   N   K   E   Y   J
C   V   T   W   Y   Z   J   N   X   R   D   D   Y   L   R
V   B   N   P   J   K   J   I   R   J   F   A   O   C   G
F   Y   C   R   C   O   T   U   Y   G   U   E   G   O   J
S   S   J   W   P   I   G   Q   P   Y   Q   K   P   Q   B

H   M   P   N   N   Q   U   Z   Z   D   W   Z   M   Y   G
Z   M   A   Y   P   I   L   Q   Z   C   D   I   B   Q   J
W   P   L   D   G   B   J   K   M   V   P   C   N   O   E
T   J   Q   B   Q   V   Q   N   Y   Z   B   S   V   Q   E
D   D   Y   I   A   O   Z   B   G   Q   W   C   M   D   Z
E   V   G   F   I   A   P   A   V   U   S   I   J   K   D
V   C   T   Z   P   Z   D   J   J   V   R   T   T   Q   P
R   C   R   F   I   E   L   Y   S   X   A   W   J   V   F
Z   P   F   C   O   I   O   E   M   X   L   A   E   K   I
S   E   P   Y   I   O   I   B   M   Q   E   N   B   H   W
C   E   E   Z   O   Q   F   R   H   Z   V   A   Z   B   P
G   Z   S   E   R   W   R   M   K   O   Q   E   U   H   Z
G   W   F   U   B   T   I   G   K   H   C   T   I   P   U
A   Q   D   F   Z   I   J   I   Q   I   Z   E   O   P   I
V   Q   B   Q   T   U   U   H   M   W   W   Q   J   H   N
```

---

**Hint 1**

> All good excavations require manipulation of the excavation site. Perhaps you should print out the blueprints and work from there?

**Hint 2 (updated)**

> What should you do with the layers? There may be some hints in the letters scattered about.

**Hint 3**

> If you've found a word in the first layer, try finding another one using the second!

**Hint 4**

> Start with the first layer and excavate it before adding in the second layer. Keep in mind the previous hint while doing so!

Comment: So, I see what your first hint suggests, but doing so makes no use of your "*Expect plenty of overlap!*" remark, as far as I can see (so I'm not sure what that's about). Its size is then perfect for rot13(bireynlvat) but I'm not finding anything especially useful when doing so (other than 5 letter correspondences in the first one and 2 in the second, if you know what I mean)... Just wanted to say that I am trying to solve this but just not getting far at the moment! :)

Comment: We need a hint!

Comment: What *do* I do with layers? *I* make onions and ogres.

Comment: / and donkeys too.

Comment: Of course it's obvious we put the areas of excavation on the letter matrixes, but what to do next O_O

Comment: Progress so far with the grids: I can see (very prominently) rot13(gur jbeq YVGUBFCURER engure ncgyl va gur gbc yriry. Ybbxvat sbe eryngrq jbeqf va gur bguref V pna svaq FBVY va gur frpbaq ohg fb sne bayl fhofgevatf (r.t  BFCURE) va gur bguref.) Nothing yet worthy of an answer though...

Comment: I am guessing we need to stack these grids into a 3D matrix and find words inside of that using the provided excavation plans. What I don't understand is why there are 5 plans instead of 6?

Comment: God forgive me, but I ran a word-search on the 3d matrix (stacked layers) with all possible 26 directions. No word with a length greater than 5 is anything suspicious, other than LITHOSPHERE, of course. Maybe we have to "shift" certain rows/cols of layers to the right/left, according to the 15x15 square the excavation plans produce (so that all letters match with the first layer?)... Or just a straight up letter shift...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is:

> **EARTH SCIENCE**

---

Look down on the top layer. One long word is very prominently visible. That word is:

> **[LITHOSPHERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithosphere)** i.e. the outermost layer of the Earth's crust.
>
>  [image: Layer 1 - LITHOSPHERE]
>
>  Furthermore, one of the irregular shapes from the excavation plans can be found in this grid (shaded light grey, above), with the locations of the D and Z exactly matching. This is the area we must *excavate*, by 'digging down to the next layer, here' i.e. **by replacing the letters in the grid in these shaded spaces with those from the layer below**.

When we do that, we can spot another word in the new grid:

> **[ASTHENOSPHERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asthenosphere)** - in geology, this is the next layer beneath the lithosphere when heading to the centre of the Earth, i.e. the upper mantle - we have a clear theme emerging!
>
>  [image: Level 2 - ASTHENOSPHERE]
>
>  Again, we can helpfully map one of the irregular shapes onto the grid (this time, the H-V shape). Let's excavate this next, 'digging down' to the third letter grid in each of the spaces covered by this shape.

Doing that, another new word becomes apparent:

> **[MESOSPHERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_mantle_(Earth))** - the lower mantle.
>
>  [image: Level 3 - MESOSPHERE]
>
>  And within this grid we can spot the A-J shape - so that's our next target area.

Excavate this area down to level 4, and we get the following new grid, concealing the words:

> **OUTER CORE** - the next geological layer of the Earth...
>
>  [image: Level 4 - OUTER CORE]
>
>  Here, we can spot the F-H shape lurking.

Excavate this down to level 5 to find:

> **INNER CORE** - we've reached the centre of the Earth!
>
>  [image: Level 5 - INNER CORE]
>
>  The final irregular shape can be spotted here (Q-G).

Excavating this final sector down to level 6 means we end up with the following state of play:

> [image: Final state of play]
>
>  And look at that - there are some more words formed in the grid - an instruction! **TAKE PIECES, FORM GRID**.
>
>  This is clearly a hint for us to notice that the 5 irregular shapes can be arranged without overlap to form a perfect square.

With a nudge from @Deusovi to get me over the finish line, we specifically need to do this using:

> the letters contained in the irregular shapes *at the point that we excavated them*. This yields the following grid:
>
>  [image: Irregular pieces assembled]

And finally, we can read off the final answer:

> If we highlight all the 'X's in the grid, then we note that between each pair we can see real words, evenly spaced down the centre of the grid:
>
>  [image: Final coded message]
>
>  ...which tells us that **THE ANSWER IS EARTH SCIENCE** - very fitting for our geological journey through the layers of the Earth! (And indeed the title - an 'excavation study' if ever there was one!) Very creative puzzle - just took us a while to get there!

Comment: Instead, putting the pieces *you dug out* together gives the following grid, which spells out the solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6kZH.png

Comment: @Deusovi Oh, beautifully done - great spot! (There's a THE at the top too...) Will update my answer in the morning when my laptop is back on again!

Comment: @Deusovi also xthex

Comment: Solution looks good all around, hope you had fun! Regarding the third layer: I'll take a look at your grid later and see if I can spot any errors, since I'm pretty sure the plan used on it is correct

Comment: @HTM I think I see now: there was an error in your text transcript of the grids (which is what I copied to Excel). There's an F in place of the J which appears in the grid images above it... Haven't checked if everything else is correct, but this was the only thing that interfered with the solution at least.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting, don't know how that letter specifically mutated - perhaps I accidentally overlaid the wrong plan over that part? Fixed now, of course, so you can complete your solution

Comment: Also, regarding the final extraction step: rot13(zl vagrag sbe guvf chmmyr jnf sbe gur fbyire gb rvgure cevag bhg gur tevqf naq "qvt" bhg gur cvrprf hfvat fpvffbef naq gncr/tyhr, be hfr vzntr rqvgvat fbsgjner gb fvzhyngr gung. Gura gurer jbhyq or ab pubvpr ohg gb hfr gur phg-bhg cvrprf sbe gur svany tevq. V gubhtug gung hfvat n fcernqfurrg jbhyq or gbb qvssvphyg, ohg V'ir orra cebira jebat V thrff :) )

Comment: @HTM Ha, it definitely was difficult! Will fix up the now-corrected part as soon as I can...

Comment: Bounty awarded! Good job cracking this after so long :)

Comment: @HTM Thanks for the bounty - a great puzzle, even though it took us so long to work out what to do!